# numpy cumsum( ) not working?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sum

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np

a = [4,6,12]

np.cumsum(a)

print(a)
```

Instead of getting `[4,10,22]`, I am still getting `[4,6,12]`. I am confused. So if `cumsum()` is not the way to do accumulation sum, what I should do then? Thanks.

Comment: `print(np.cumsum(a))` -- the function isn't in-place.

Comment: @CongMa Thanks. if you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: glad to be of help

Comment: @CongMa OK. I really think the credit should go to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docstring of `numpy.cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.cumsum.html) says:

> Return the cumulative sum of the elements along the given axis.

So that means it returns a new array. It does not modify the existing array.

Answer (score 1):

```
b = np.cumsum(a)

print(b)
```

You are not storing the output of `np.cumsum()`